# How can I say "girl" in archaic English?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms, archaicisms

I'm looking for an archaic replacement for the word *girl* ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You could call her a *maiden* or *maid* or *lass*.

Answer (score 8):

I would go with *damsel*, or maybe a *wench* (but it can also be associated with “prostitute”, so…).

Answer (score 2):

Gel, but it's lower class talk.  (hard G)

Comment: Really? That's lower class? As an AmE speaker, it sounds kinda 'upstairs'.

Comment: Has that anything to do with *gal*?

Comment: It's probably a vowel shift that became formalized.  But I'll leave it to the linguists to debate.

Answer (score 1):

Don't replace “girl”, just because it doesn't sound like you'd expect early ME to sound. In fact, “girl” has been in use since the Middle English period, which is much earlier than what you're going for.

Comment: Yes, but it had a different meaning - it meant any child.  See http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=girl&allowed_in_frame=0